# don't load readline module in irb

Tags: ruby, irb, libreadline

The `readline` extension on my OSX seems buggy.

```
$irb -f --noreadline
irb(main):001:0> "中文"
=> "中文"

$irb -f --readline
irb(main):001:0> \U+FFE4\U+FFB8\U+FFAD\U+FFE6
```

So I want to set `--noreadline` as default option for irb. how to do it?

p.s. I'm using `RVM` and `Ruby` 1.9.3p194.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.irbrc` file (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = false
```

Alternatively, you can add this to `/etc/irbrc` if you want it to apply across user accounts, or `foo/.irbrc` if you want it to apply on a directory/project basis.

Here's a [list of other useful config options](http://www.rubycentral.org/pickaxe/irb.html).